# Join multiple select quires

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a [TABLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f27a09/49) and the query I wrote works fine on fiddle, but when implementing it on the actual server, I get the following error

1054 - Unknown column 't2.EmpName' in 'on clause'

Fiddle is mysql 5.6, i'm running ver 15.1 MariaDB

Thanks for your help!  Here is my query:

```
select
    table1.EmpName as "Employee",
    table1.weekof as "Week Of",
    t2.pph as "Previous PPH",
    table1.pph as "Current PPH",
    table1.quality as "Quality"
from table1 t2
join
table1 on t2.EmpName = table1.EmpName
where t2.weekof = '9/11/2017' and table1.weekof = '9/18/2017'
```

Comment: It works on rextester too. [Look](http://rextester.com/AZAR18277)

Comment: I guess you don't have a column named `empName`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, but your ON clause `on t2.EmpName = table1.EmpName` has a smell.  Just use `ON t1.EmpName = t2.EmpName` and alias the table with `t1` and `t2`.  MySQL will swallow a lot of bad code and still run, but you should not be relying on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you have some difference beetween the code in sqlfiddle and the code  you are using on the server
anyway for a better legibility  and for avoid mismacth i suggest you a more clear use of the alias  (expecially when you use self join )
and don't use quote for column name  use backctics when you need eg:

```
  select
    t1.EmpName as Employee,
    t1.weekof as `Week Of`,
    t2.pph as `Previous PPH`,
    t1.pph as `Current PPH`,
    t1.quality as Quality
  from table1 t2
  join table1 t1 on t2.EmpName = t1.EmpName
  where t2.weekof = '9/11/2017' and t1.weekof = '9/18/2017'
  ;
```